# How to create a custom tab bar controller with custom tab bar shape programattically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to create my iOS mobile app entirely in code. Doing so causes problems with my custom tab bar controller with a custom tab bar shape.

[My custom tab bar shape looks something along the lines of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdzYI.png)

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    window.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

In my Custom TabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCenterButton()
    }

    func setupCenterButton() {
        let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))

        var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - 48
        menuButtonFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
        menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
        menuButton.clipsToBounds = true
        menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
        view.addSubview(menuButton)
    }


}


extension UITabBar {

    open override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: 64)
    }
}
```

And my custom tab bar shape

```
import UIKit

class CustomizedTabBar: UITabBar {

private var shapeLayer: CALayer?

private func addShape() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = createPath()

    if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
        self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
    } else {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    }

    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
}

func createPath() -> CGPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    //..path moving around..
    path.close()

    return path.cgPath
}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    //..stuff
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.addShape()
}

func createBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {

    //..creating a path
}
```

How do I get around this? With the current code setup my tabbar comes out like a normal tabbar...not my custom shape
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tql0N.png)

and I have tried to override my tab bar property in my UITabBarController to return an instance of my CustomizedBarBar class, with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure but try to add layer as mask.

Comment: Please show us the code where are you using your `CustomizedBarBar` with default tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a storyboard then using a custom tab bar is trivial.

1. Create your custom UITabBar subclass.
2. Drag a tab bar controller onto your storyboard.
3. Select the tab bar object in the storyboard, click on the "Identity Inspector", and change the class of the tab bar to your custom tab bar class.

Answer (score -1):

Please try and run this way, and let me know.

```
class MyTab: UITabBar {

}
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override var tabBar: UITabBar {
        return MyTab()
    }
}
```